# Jenkins API filter artifacts

Tags: json, api, jenkins, filter, artifacts

The Jenkins API documentation is pretty well written and clear on what you can get.
So to get a list of all artifacts you could request `http://jenkins/job/myjob/../api/json?tree=artifacts[*]`.

What I was not able to find is a way to filter this list of artifacts, like e.g. `http://jenkins/job/myjob/../api/json?tree=artifacts[relativePath="/dist/**/theme.min.css"]`.
Is there a way to filter artifacts like this?

I would like to use the tree parameter instead of xml with xpath and exclude to avoid the memory spike on the server while building the DOM (as mentioned in the docs)